# showing that $\mathbb{Q}(7^{1/4},i) : \mathbb{Q} $ is normal

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, galois-theory

showing that $\mathbb{Q}(7^{1/4},i) : \mathbb{Q} $ is normal

if I let $f(x) = (x^4-7)(x^2+1)$ this obviously splits over $\mathbb{Q}(7^{1/4},i)$ so does that immediately mean that $\mathbb{Q}(7^{1/4},i) : \mathbb{Q} $ is normal or do we need $f$ to be irreducible? i.e. do we have to use $f(x) = x^4 - 7$

Comment: As you say, $(x^4-7)(x^2+1)$ splits over your field.  If you can show that it doesn't split over a smaller field, then it is a splitting field and therefore normal.

Comment: Also, you can use the fact that a compositum of normal extensions is normal.

Comment: @Slade any idea of how to show it does not split over a smaller field?

Comment: Show that it's generated by the roots.

Comment: Well each polynomial is irreducible over Q (think eisenstein), so that is part one

Comment: wouldn't it be easier to use $x^4-7$ which is irreducible? ASKASK what do you mean by part one?

Comment: If you adjoin all the roots of a polynomial $f$, irreducible or not, to a field $k$, the extension is the splitting field of $f$ over $k$. In the case of $f=x^2-3$ and $k=\Bbb Q(i)$, the splitting field is $\Bbb Q(i,\sqrt3)$, even though the polynomial splits over the smaller field $\Bbb Q(\sqrt3)$. So it is not correct to say that it’s necessary to show that the polynomial fails to split over any smaller field.